# core data invalid redeclaration of class

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So, I have a got a problem…

[image] when I intend to create a `NSManagedObject` Subclass.

As you can see this problem is really spread widely. Many people propose a solution by changing codegen block into Manual/None. But this did not help me, furthermore Class Definition and Category/Extension did not resolve too.

When I delete two files which were created by tapping in Product/Create NSManagedObject, the code is really works. I didn't why but I could use a NSManObject classes like they are lying somewhere I found a path where they are existing.

[image]

I thought If I delete them then I can recreate subclass again and use it successfully. But it is not. When I create again a subclass files these two files that were lying in unknown directory were recreated again! I ask the people who encountered to this problem and I need their help or solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an annoying bug in the core data codegen settings, which means that updated settings aren't stored correctly.

If you change the codegen settings and then Build or Run, your changes will not be saved. For example, if you changed from **Category/Extension** to **None** and deleted the generated file, it will be recreated.

To solve this problem…

- Change your codegen settings
- Save the .xcdatamodel file.
- Close all project windows.
- Re-open the project.

Answer (score -1):

I tested for different Core Data data model class codegen settings. When it's set to Class Definition or Category/Extension. The builder will generate subclass files automatically. So we don't need to add these files by ourselves. The following is files generated by builder.
[image]